# how to escape quote in header php

Tags: php

I tried half day on searching on the net already see my code below

```
<?php 
  header("Refresh: 2;url=test.php?ID=".$_GET['ID']"&UID=".$_GET['uid']);
  echo "<img src='images/loading.gif'/>";
?>
```

I know the problem is with the quotes within the header code.
Anybody can correct that for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are that unversed with string syntax, use a simpler one:

```
header("Refresh: 2;url=test.php?ID=$_GET[ID]&UID=$_GET[uid]");
```

(Omitting array key quotes is only allowed in double quoted string context!)

Comment: thanks that works believe or not i did try that

Comment: @BhoshanMoheeputh That's also unsafe because the parameters are not escaped properly.

Comment: @Jack: Yours is obviously the only proper solution. I'd go for double quotes still with  `header("Refresh: 2; URL=test.php?{$_GET->multi->http_build_query['ID,UID']}");`

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the arguments that you receive from the query string!

Use `http_build_query()` to construct the query string:

```
header("Refresh: 2;url=test.php?" . http_build_query(array(
    'ID' => $_GET['ID'],
    'UID' => $_GET['uid'],
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlencode($_GET['...'])` where header could contain parts of url.

Answer (score 0):

you miss the  `.`

```
<?php 

header("Refresh: 2;url=test.php?ID=".$_GET['ID']."&UID=".$_GET['uid']);

// or header("Refresh: 2;url=test.php?ID=$_GET['ID']&UID=$_GET['uid']");

echo "<img src='images/loading.gif'/>";

?>
```